# Change color of statusBar in splashScreen react-native android

Tags: android, xml, react-native

[image]

I try to add a splash screen to a RN app. As you can see in the gif the status bar color is changing to black while the splash screen is on, but i can't find the problem exactly.
I have followed this tutorial to implement the splash screen: [Add splash screen to RN app](https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9)
Please find here the code i added to android studio:

in `AndroidManifest.xml` =>

```
<activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

in `styles.xml` =>

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <!-- Add the following line to set the default status bar color for all the app. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/mdcGreen</item>
    <!-- Add the following line to set the default status bar text color for all the app
    to be a light color (false) or a dark color (true) -->
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    <!-- Add the following line to set the default background color for all the app. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<!-- Adds the splash screen definition -->
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/mdcGreen</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

in `drawable/background_splash.xml` =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/mdcGreen"/>

    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/mdc"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

in `layout/launch_screen.xml` =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
    android:statusBarColor="@color/mdcGreen">

</LinearLayout>
```

**THANKS!**

Comment: Please add <StatusBar 
backgroundColor="<code for mdcGreen>"
barStyle="light-content" /> to your template

Comment: I did already in ```app.js```. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to the problem after a bit of googling. Following are the steps I followed to setup splash screen in android app and also, resolve the intermediary black status bar issue which shows up between native splash screen and JavaScript loading.

1. Follow this tutorial to setup splash screen for both android and iOS (excellent tutorial) - [React Native Splash screen setup](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)
2. Once you have followed the above tutorial and completed the setup there is a thing to note. In the above article author talks about rendering *ImageView* inside *LinearLayout* and how to avoid jump issue during splash screen switching by setting *android:layout_marginTop* to *24dp*. There is a **fix for this** which I used and worked perfectly fine in my case. Follow the below steps to avoid hard coding:

   - 2.1. Replace your layout/launch_screen.xml with below:

     ```
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center">
      </LinearLayout>
     ```
   - 2.2. Note that in above LinearLayout the **android:background** is replaced with **@drawable/background_splash**.
   - 2.3. Make sure in your styles.xml ***SplashTheme*** is having **android:background** item as such:

     ```
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
     ```
   - 2.4. This will help to maintain the icon on the splash screen centered. Read along to solve the status bar issue.
3. Follow the below steps to solve intermediary black status bar issue.

   - 3.1. In your `android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml` add `status_bar_color`:

     ```
     <resources>
         <color name="splashscreen_bg">#fff</color>
         <color name="app_bg">#fff</color>
         <color name="status_bar_color"><!--  Colour of your Status Bar --></color>
     </resources>
     ```
   - 3.2. Create a style definition (or add to existing) for this in `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`:

     ```
        <resources>
            <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
                <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar_color</item>
            </style>
        </resources>
     ```
   - 3.3. In your ***MainActivity.java*** change your `show` method to include your custom style:

     ```
         SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme);
     ```
   - **Note:** The symbol after the R.style. should match the name of the theme inside ***`styles.xml`***. In this example, name of the theme is `SplashTheme`

Providing reference comments to the above solution:

- [Step 2 solution reference](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/241#issuecomment-458985596)
- [Step 3 solution reference](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/95#issuecomment-414363569)

***I hope this helps. Cheers!***

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Library for *splash screen*, what you can do make a simple component for splash screen and in componentDidMount() function, you can navigate to another screen which will comes after the splash. In this case, you have full control over the splash and it is highly customizable. Also you don't have to add an extra library for splash.

Sample code for implementing **SplashScreen.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.NavigateToNextScreen(), 4000)
}

NavigateToNextScreen(){
    // code for navigation to next screen according to your requirement    
}
```

Finally customize your status bar in render funtion of the splash screen as RN provides Status bar element for implementing splash

```
<StatusBar
  hidden={true}
  backgroundColor={'<your color>'}
  barStyle='light-content'
/>
```

Don't forget to import it from react native module

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'
```

Hope this helps...Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i understand your concerne of keeping control and not using libraries for every problem we encounter, but for now i cant turn back as i believe i need just some kind of attribute/ value some where in android xml files. thanks again.